# Cognito authentication from filebeat

Tags: filebeat, amazon-cognito

I added security to AWS Kibana using [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/get-started-with-amazon-elasticsearch-service-use-amazon-cognito-for-kibana-access-control/) blog. Kibana is now secure and I have to login with a user from the user pool. But now filebeat can't write to the elastic search endpoint anymore. I tried adding the username and password to filebeat config, but I still get **Failed to connect: 403 Forbidden**. If I remove Cognito authentication filebeat can write again.

Any help on this would be appreciated

Comment: were you able to get this fixed? I'm facing the same issue now

Comment: No I was not. At the end of the day I added nginx in front of elastic search and kibana.

Comment: Does Cognito authentication support using tokens or client id/ client secret sent via HEADERS ? If yes, in filebeat.yml you can add cusom HTTP headers for every request sent. That way filebeat can authenticate to ES/ Kibana successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filebeat doesn't have an option for anything other than Basic Auth, so it isn't possible to configure it in a way that works for AWS Kibana. We went around this issue by whitelisting the IP address of the machine on the access policy of our Kibana instance.